# Near / Near Table creates -1 values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, spatial-analyst, proximity

I have two feature classes.

1. Point feature of hand-sampled GPS locations
2. Line feature of terrace walls digitized from aerial photograph.

[image: sample points and terrace walls]

Because of the less than perfect ways I generated these features, I need to allocate each GPS point to the nearest terrace wall from which I sampled it.

I defined the Input as the Point Feature, and the near feture as the terrace lines.

[image: near tool]

But the process fails to generate results.
If it's a Near Table, then it's an empty one, and when I use the Near Tool itself on the point feature, it adds two fields with -1 in them.

[image: Point feature with -1]

When I run the tool on the features in an opposite way, it does generate results, and for every terrace walls gives me the nearest point - obviously, not what I'm looking for.

Any idea why the process fails?

Comment: Are the projections defined and the same for both layers?

Comment: Yes they are. Like I said, doing it the other way round worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have tried the **[Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000)** tool but what is not clear is the search radius that you have used.

Expand the tool dialog by dragging its corner (or use the scroll bar) to see what it is defaulting to and then try increasing it because:

> The values for NEAR_FID and NEAR_DIST will be -1 if no feature is
>   found within the search radius.